# How to get value from json by key as a variable in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying for fetching  some data from below json

```
[
    {
        "company": "XYZ",
        "companyAddress": "PQR",
        "staffDetails": [
            {
                "employeeCount": {
                    "jobLevel1": "9",
                    "jobLevel2": "10",
                    "jobLevel3": "11"
                },
                "otherStaff": {
                    "jobLevel1": "99",
                    "jobLevel2": "100"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    
    {
        "company": "XXX",
        "companyAddress": "YYY",
        "staffDetails": [
            {
                "employeeCount": {
                    "jobLevel1": "9",
                    "jobLevel2": "10",
                    "jobLevel3": "11"
                },
                "otherStaff": {
                    "jobLevel1": "99",
                    "jobLevel2": "100"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What data i want to fetch is configurable.
e.g. below 2 details i want.

config.properties

```
[details]
reqparameters=staffDetails.employeeCount.joblevel1 ,staffDetails.otherStaff.joblevel2
```

myPython code is like below-

```
   import configparser
    import json
    config=configparser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read('config.properties')
    parameters=config.get('details','reqparameters')
    splitedValue=responseDetails.split(",")
    resp='''    [
            {
                "company": "XYZ",
                "companyAddress": "PQR",
                "staffDetails": [
                    {
                        "employeeCount": {
                            "jobLevel1": "9",
                            "jobLevel2": "10",
                            "jobLevel3": "11"
                        },
                        "otherStaff": {
                            "jobLevel1": "99",
                            "jobLevel2": "100"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            
            {
                "company": "XXX",
                "companyAddress": "YYY",
                "staffDetails": [
                    {
                        "employeeCount": {
                            "jobLevel1": "9",
                            "jobLevel2": "10",
                            "jobLevel3": "11"
                        },
                        "otherStaff": {
                            "jobLevel1": "99",
                            "jobLevel2": "100"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]'''
    #x = json.loads(resp, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))
    x = json.loads(resp)
    
    for property in splitedValue:
     for jNode in x:
       print(jNode[property])
       print(jNode.property)
```

tried both the ways print(jNode[property]) & print(jNode.property) along with x = json.loads(resp, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d)) but it's not working . **As my input is configurable i can't harcode that with jNode so need it with dynamically using variable property which i am reading from properties file**

Comment: you can use the  JsonCustomEncoder/Decoder like this:```x = json.loads(resp, cls=JsonCustomDecoder)``` google ```python Json Custom Decoder```you can know the way to write JsonCustomEncoder

Answer (score 0):

This is not how JSON handling works in Python to access the sections you need would use:

```
jNode['staffDetails'][0]['employeeCount']['jobLevel1']
```

There is an issue in your data the config file says `joblevel1` but the key in the json is `jobLevel1` (capital L)
The other issue you are going to have here is that `staffDetails` is a list so do you know that it will always be one element? or could it be more?

Doing this directly in Python would be messy e.g.

```
In [564]:
    ...: for config in splitedValue:
    ...:     for company in x:
    ...:         data = company
    ...:         for node in config.split('.'):
    ...:             if isinstance(data, type(list)):
    ...:                 data = data[0]
    ...:             data = data[node]
    ...:         print(f"company: {company['company']} {config}: {data}")
    ...:
company: XYZ staffDetails.employeeCount.jobLevel1: 9
company: XXX staffDetails.employeeCount.jobLevel1: 9
company: XYZ staffDetails.otherStaff.jobLevel2: 100
company: XXX staffDetails.otherStaff.jobLevel2: 100
```

Personally I would look at making changes to the JSON and the config file to make them work better together

Comment: apr_1985 staffDetails can contain muliple elements. is above solution handles that ?

Comment: nope.  You would need to make the line `data = data[0]` a loop through the staffDetails list (currently held in `data`) instead.